# Ubuntu suddenly stops booting into GUI

Tags: boot, 20.04, nvidia, xorg, gui

I have recently got a HP firefly laptop. The laptop came with windows but I made it dual boot with ubuntu 20.04. The system was working fine with either of the operating systems.

Now yesterday I left my computer on overnight (without external power) and in the morning I found it switched off probably because the battery drained off. Now, when I connected to power and booted into ubuntu I could not see the GUI. Only a sad cursor blinking on the left top corner of the screen. Note I don't see any message.

As I could login tty2-tty6, I logged in and used

> sudo startx

and changed the nvidia driver to xorg driver. When I rebooted I got some errors. Please note that when I used startx on tty2 the GUI appeared.

I again went back to tty2 and selected nvidia proprietary driver 460 and rebooted. Now the GUI appeared. But when I restarted again the same sad cursor blinking alone on the right top corner of the screen.

I am clueless about the problem. Can you tell me what can I do to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: I found that initially I updated my laptop to 5.11.0-40-generic kernel. If I revert back to original 5.11.0-27-generic kernel everything is fine. I think it is not an answer but a workaround.

Comment: My comment here might be applicable: https://askubuntu.com/a/1376208/1542653